# How to enable/disable SelectManyCheck based on method returned value?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Can anyone help in getting the returned value from a method in a bean to enable/disable components through ajax ex(SelectManyCheckbox, textbox ..etc) in a jsf page based on the selected radio button. First the SelectManyCheckbox component should disabled and based on the selection it should be enabled. The method is checking whether the value is "A" or "B" and it will return the value. Here is the method code:

```
private String firstToggle="True";    
public String firstToggle(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){

        firstToggle=requestType;
        System.out.print("Value "+firstToggle);

        return firstToggle;
    }
```

Here it will return A or B.

However, When I am trying to disable/enable the SelectManyCheckbox component, the SelectManyCheckbox component won't pickup the value in the disabled attribute when the Value is B.

```
 <p:selectManyCheckbox id="Cars" value="#{user.xyz}" layout="pageDirection" disabled="#{user.firstToggle}=='B')">
<f:selectItems value="#{user.xyz}" var="xyz" itemLabel="#{xyz}" itemValue="#{xyz}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

So please help

Comment: `disabled="#{user.firstToggle eq 'B'}"` (but only if everything else is also correct).

Comment: Thanks but by default I would like the SelectManyCheckbox to be disabled, so how to do this

Comment: You can assign `firstToggle` a value other than `B` on page load then.

Comment: I am assigning it to "True" value at the initiation at the top in the bean. Can you please guide me more as I assigned 'Q' value and when it loads, it will not match the condition #{user.firstToggle eq 'B'} and it will fail

Comment: If I were you, I would just declare `firstToggle` as a `Boolean`/`boolean` instance member of the bean so that it could just be possible to do  `disabled="#{user.firstToggle}"` on the XHTML side instead.

Comment: @Tiny Then I will be having a problem of evaluating the disabled attribute

Comment: @Tiny I tried boolean but it didn't work as I am having 2 SelectManyCheckbox where one should be enabled and the other should be disabled. In the case which you have explained all of them are enabled  together or disabled.

Comment: `disabled` just requires a boolean value. The logic you put to make them either enable or disable should be giving you troubles. You may want to edit the question with your new attempts. It is important where and how you set the value in the bean and which scope the bean is but before that I hope, you will have solved the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't want to use `firstToggle` as a `Boolean`/`boolean` as suggested per Tiny's comment is really not clear! However, if you have your reasons to do that or you are handling the `firstToggle` in another place and you want to use it's value 'A' or 'B' in two different `p:selectManyCheckbox` ("where one should be enabled and the other should be disabled" as you said), then you could implement the **first one** with `disabled="#{user.firstToggle eq 'B'}"` and the **second one** with `disabled="#{user.firstToggle eq 'A'}"` or `disabled="#{user.firstToggle ne 'B'}"`.

In case, you want to work with `Boolean`/`boolean` following Tiny's suggestion, then just use the **first one** with `disabled="#{user.firstToggle}"` and the **second one** with `disabled="#{not user.firstToggle}"`

**NB:** Also `private String firstToggle="True";` even if it's correct, it doesn't make any sense, either use `Boolean`/`boolean` and assigne `true` to it, or assign `'A'` which seems to mean `false` regarding your context.